# Convert 64bit hex to Windows datetime

Tags: c#, python, hex

I need to convert a windows hex 64 bit (big endian) date time to something readable in python?

example 'abaaaaaaccd3e340'

converts to "Tue, 29 June 2010 09:47:42 UTC"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303344-converting-windows-64-bit-time-to-python-useable-f/

This might help...

Comment: I couldn't know how to apply the source. I want to know the usage. Please give me know the usage exatly and explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks word-for-word like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869769/convert-64-bit-windows-date-time-in-python/4870249#4870249), but your example number is different, although the date/time is *exactly* the same.

Comment: Hex value of the above links makes output of date normally,  but the hex vale in my question applys the source, then the data occur overflow. I thought that the problem is due to structure. Please let me know what's the problem and how to solve this problem. I want to make the output of date normally using the hex in my question.


Thanks : )