# Convert 18-digit LDAP/FILETIME timestamps to human readable date

Tags: python, datetime

I have exported a list of AD Users out of AD and need to validate their login times.

The output from the powershell script give lastlogin as LDAP/FILE time

**EXAMPLE 130305048577611542**

I am having trouble converting this to readable time in pandas

Im using the following code:

**df['date of login'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FileTime'], unit='ns')**

The column FileTime contains time formatted like the EXAMPLE above.

Im getting the following output in my new column date of login

**EXAMPLE 1974-02-17 03:50:48.577611542**

I know this is being parsed incorrectly as when i input this date time on a online converter i get this output

**EXAMPLE:**

**Epoch/Unix time: 1386031258
GMT: Tuesday, December 3, 2013 12:40:58 AM
Your time zone: Monday, December 2, 2013 4:40:58 PM GMT-08:00**

Anyone have an idea of what occuring here why are all my dates in the 1970'

Comment: I would consider it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869769/convert-64-bit-windows-date-time-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert 64 bit windows date time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869769/convert-64-bit-windows-date-time-in-python)

Answer (score 10):

The 18-digit Active Directory timestamps (LDAP), also named 'Windows NT time format', 'Win32 FILETIME or SYSTEMTIME', or NTFS file time.

These are used in Microsoft Active Directory for `pwdLastSet`, `accountExpires`, `LastLogon`, `LastLogonTimestamp`, and `LastPwdSet`.

The timestamp is the number of 100-nanoseconds intervals (1 nanosecond = one billionth of a second) since Jan 1, 1601 UTC.

Therefore, `130305048577611542` does indeed relate to `December 3, 2013`.

When putting this value through the date time function in Python, it is truncating the value to nine digits. Therefore the timestamp becomes `130305048` and goes from `1.1.1970` which does result in a `1974` date!

In order to get the correct Unix timestamp you need to do:

`(130305048577611542 / 10000000) - 11644473600`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I did in Python that worked well for me:

```
import datetime

def ad_timestamp(timestamp):
    if timestamp != 0:
        return datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=timestamp/10000000)
    return np.nan
```

So then if you need to convert a Pandas column:

```
df.lastLogonTimestamp = df.lastLogonTimestamp.fillna(0).apply(ad_timestamp)
```

Note: I needed to use `fillna` before using `apply`. Also, since I filled with 0's, I checked for that in the conversion function about, `if timestamp != 0`. Hope that makes sense. It's extra stuff but you may need it to convert the column in question.

Answer (score 1):

I've been stuck on this for couple of days. But now i am ready to share really working solution in more easy to use form:

```
import datetime
timestamp = 132375402928051110
value = datetime.datetime (1601, 1, 1) +   
datetime.timedelta(seconds=timestamp/10000000) ### combine str 3 and 4  
print(value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```