# Convert Microsoft Binary Format Timestamp to Python unix timestamp

Tags: python

I am given timestamps in binary format example:

5249363694976427904

How can I convert this to unix timestamp in Python?

I was pointed to the following website about the format but its in C#: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=net-5.0)

The following link is the function in c# that is used to generate this binary date time in c#: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tobinary?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert 64 bit windows date time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869769/convert-64-bit-windows-date-time-in-python)

Comment: Could you please provide more explanations? the given number is not even binary! A binary number contains ones and zeros only.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It isn't the same as it contains according to the link a 2bit field to mark timestamp as local, UTC or unspecified. Moreover its epoch is year 1 of the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: i dont think the suggested answer solves my problem

Comment: that is a different format then mine, please see the following link which is the function used in c# to convert to the binary representation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tobinary?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int` is a representation of a set of 2-bit and 62-bit values, [the first being the `Kind` of timestamp (UTC, local, undefined)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=net-5.0). The second is the [number of ticks since 0001-01-01 00:00:00](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0#remarks), where each tick is [defined as 0.1 microseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0#remarks).

So we just need to convert the `int` back to binary, split it into each part, convert to microseconds and then add a `timedelta` to our base date.

This should do it for you:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def ticks_to_datetime(binary_time: int) -> datetime:
    binary_time_string = f"{binary_time:064b}"

    # Not used here, but you can expand to check based on
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=net-5.0
    time_kind = binary_time_string[:2]

    time_microseconds = int(binary_time_string[2:], 2) / 10
    time_difference = timedelta(microseconds=time_microseconds)
    return datetime(1, 1, 1) + time_difference

my_time = ticks_to_datetime(5249363694976427904)
print(f"{my_time} | {my_time.timestamp()}")
```

Result:

```
2021-09-20 20:47:34.904000 | 1632170854.904
[Finished in 68ms]
```

Note that I'm not handling the `Kind` of the binary time, so if you find yourself needing to deal with timestamps from local timezones, you'll need to modify the `datetime` on the `return` line to take this into account.